GCP database migration fails while recreating indexes
I created a continuous database migration job from an AWS RDS MySQL database to GCP Cloud SQL instance. Everything seemed to go well, until 8 hours in, I notice the new database size went to 0 and I get this error in the migration logs:
Error:
ERROR: While recreating indexes for table crm.organizations: MySQL Error 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry 'NULL' for key 'organizations.idx_organizations_url'
Full log entry:
DUMP_STAGE(RETRY): Attempt 1/2: import failed: loadDump stderr: ERROR: While recreating indexes for table crm.organizations: MySQL Error 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry 'NULL' for key 'organizations.idx_organizations_url': ALTER TABLE crm.organizations ADD FULLTEXT KEY idx_organizations_organizationName_city (organizationName,city),ADD KEY idx_organizations_Company_Id (Company_Id),ADD KEY idx_organizations_state (state),ADD KEY idx_organizations_insertDate (insertDate),ADD KEY idx_organizations_updateDate (updateDate),ADD KEY idx_organizations_organizationName (organizationName),ADD KEY idx_organizations_city (city),ADD KEY idx_organizations_postalCode (postalCode),ADD KEY idx_organizations_industry (industry),ADD KEY idx_organizations_specialty (specialty),ADD KEY idx_organizations_userId (userId),ADD KEY idx_organizations_dateLastActivity (dateLastActivity),ADD KEY idx_organizations_organizationType (organizationType),ADD KEY idx_organizations_phone (phone),ADD KEY idx_organizations_url (url) , ERROR: [Worker000]: While recreating indexes for table crm.organizations: Duplicate entry 'NULL' for key 'organizations.idx_organizations_url'
I don't understand why it's complaining about a duplicate entry for the url index, while there are definitely a number of records with a null url, the index is not a unique index.
Here is the table structure:
CREATE TABLE `organizations` (
  `organizationId` binary(16) NOT NULL,
  `uuid` varchar(36) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (insert(insert(insert(insert(lower(hex(`organizationId`)),9,0,_utf8mb4'-'),14,0,_utf8mb4'-'),19,0,_utf8mb4'-'),24,0,_utf8mb4'-')) VIRTUAL,
  `Company_Id` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `organizationName` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `address1` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `address2` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `city` varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL,
  `state` varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL,
  `postalCode` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `country` varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL,
  `latitude` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `longitude` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `url` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fax` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `industry` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `specialty` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `notes` longtext,
  `userId` binary(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `userUuid` varchar(36) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (insert(insert(insert(insert(lower(hex(`userId`)),9,0,_utf8mb4'-'),14,0,_utf8mb4'-'),19,0,_utf8mb4'-'),24,0,_utf8mb4'-')) VIRTUAL,
  `organizationType` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'organizationType',
  `dateLastActivity` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `insertDate` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updateDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`organizationId`),
  KEY `idx_organizations_Company_Id` (`Company_Id`),
  KEY `idx_organizations_state` (`state`),
  KEY `idx_organizations_insertDate` (`insertDate`),
  KEY `idx_organizations_updateDate` (`updateDate`),
  KEY `idx_organizations_organizationName` (`organizationName`),
  KEY `idx_organizations_city` (`city`),
  KEY `idx_organizations_postalCode` (`postalCode`),
  KEY `idx_organizations_industry` (`industry`),
  KEY `idx_organizations_specialty` (`specialty`),
  KEY `idx_organizations_userId` (`userId`),
  KEY `idx_organizations_dateLastActivity` (`dateLastActivity`),
  KEY `idx_organizations_organizationType` (`organizationType`),
  KEY `idx_organizations_phone` (`phone`),
  KEY `idx_organizations_url` (`url`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `idx_organizations_organizationName_city` (`organizationName`,`city`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

I tried to re-create this by dumping the source table and importing it to a local database without the indexes and then adding them in a single ALTER TABLE statement, like the migration seems to be doing, and was unable to reproduce this problem.
I will note that the AWS RDS MySQL version is 8.0.34 and the Cloud SQL MySQL version is 8.0.31, although I do not think this be a reason for the above error.
Any pointers on this is appreciated.

It does seem strange, since none of your indexes are unique indexes. MySQL will complain if you try to add an index by a name that already exists, but that error will be "Duplicate key name" not duplicate entry. The error suggests the key was created as a unique key. Have you double-checked that the table was created the same on the GCP server?

Also even if it is a unique index, MySQL allows multiple NULLs. So it must be the string value 'NULL', not an SQL NULL.

@BillKarwin I considered that, but there are no records in the source table where url = 'NULL'.
